# Is it possible to get windows logs in real time in python?

Tags: python, windows, logging

I wish to get windows logs in real time for analysis. Googled out some stuff and came up with this.

```
import win32evtlog # requires pywin32 pre-installed

 server = 'localhost' # name of the target computer to get event logs
logtype = 'System' # 'Application' # 'Security' System
hand = win32evtlog.OpenEventLog(server,logtype)
flags = win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_BACKWARDS_READ|win32evtlog.EVENTLOG_SEQUENTIAL_READ
total = win32evtlog.GetNumberOfEventLogRecords(hand)

while True:
     events = win32evtlog.ReadEventLog(hand, flags,0)
     if events:
          for event in events: 
                print 'Event Category:', event.EventCategory
                print 'Time Generated:', event.TimeGenerated
                print 'Source Name:', event.SourceName
                print 'Event ID:', event.EventID
                print 'Event Type:', event.EventType
                data = event.StringInserts
                if data:
                    print 'Event Data:'
                    for msg in data:
                        print msg\n
```

What this does is it prints all the logs from the begining till that instant of time when the code is run. Is it possible to continously monitor and get the logs printed whenever there is an update?

Comment: This method might be what you want: https://github.com/wuxc/pywin32doc/blob/master/md/win32evtlog.md#win32evtlogevtsubscribe (I found out about it via `help(win32evtlog)` and looking for something related to subscription/registering events etc)

Comment: @nitzel Can you please elaborate your statement? I am relatively new to this field.

Comment: You call that method and one of the parameters is a callback, that's a function, which is invoked when new events are logged. You'll have to figure the exact parameters out yourself or look for examples using that method.

Comment: There's some more information about the actual windows function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe which says that to end the subscription you need to invoke `EvtClose` with the return value of `EvtSubscribe`

Answer (score 3):

The python docs are [here](https://github.com/wuxc/pywin32doc/blob/master/md/win32evtlog.md#win32evtlogevtrender), but they are not too helpful so I also looked the [Microsoft C++ Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winevt/nf-winevt-evtsubscribe) which had a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/wes/subscribing-to-events)

I couldn't figure out how to get the object you received from `win32evtlog.ReadEventLog` through the events but the library allows to render to XML so with an XML parser you should be able to extract all the information you need:

```py
import win32evtlog
import pprint
import sys

# Subscribes to and logs 'application' events
# To manually fire a new event, open an admin console and type: (replace 125 with any other ID that suits you)
#   eventcreate.exe /L "application" /t warning /id 125 /d "This is a test warning"

# event_context can be `None` if not required, this is just to demonstrate how it works
event_context = { "info": "this object is always passed to your callback" }
# Event log source to listen to
event_source = 'application'

def new_logs_event_handler(reason, context, evt):
  """
  Called when new events are logged.

  reason - reason the event was logged?
  context - context the event handler was registered with
  evt - event handle
  """
  # Just print some information about the event
  print ('reason', reason, 'context', context, 'event handle', evt)

  # Render event to xml, maybe there's a way of getting an object but I didn't find it
  print('Rendered event:', win32evtlog.EvtRender(evt, win32evtlog.EvtRenderEventXml))

  # empty line to separate logs
  print(' - ')

  # Make sure all printed text is actually printed to the console now
  sys.stdout.flush()

  return 0

# Subscribe to future events
subscription = win32evtlog.EvtSubscribe(event_source, win32evtlog.EvtSubscribeToFutureEvents, None, Callback=new_logs_event_handler, Context=event_context, Query=None)
```

Output

```
reason 1 context {'info': 'this object is always passed to your callback'} event handle 1
Rendered event: <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='EventCreate'/><EventID Qualifiers='0'>125</EventID><Level>3</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2020-03-03T15:23:11.150209500Z'/><EventRecordID>1</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>mypc</Computer><Security UserID='guid'/></System><EventData><Data>This is a test warning</Data></EventData></Event>
 -
reason 1 context {'info': 'this object is always passed to your callback'} event handle 1
Rendered event: <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='EventCreate'/><EventID Qualifiers='0'>125</EventID><Level>3</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2020-03-03T15:23:17.876041700Z'/><EventRecordID>2</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>mypc</Computer><Security UserID='guid'/></System><EventData><Data>This is a test warning 2</Data></EventData></Event>
 -
reason 1 context {'info': 'this object is always passed to your callback'} event handle 1
Rendered event: <Event xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'><System><Provider Name='EventCreate'/><EventID Qualifiers='0'>125</EventID><Level>3</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime='2020-03-03T15:23:20.476312800Z'/><EventRecordID>3</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>mypc</Computer><Security UserID='guid'/></System><EventData><Data>This is a test warning 3</Data></EventData></Event>
 -
```